# Is it safe to use default value with not null on a new column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration, postgresql-11

We have a Rails app powered by Postgresql v11.4 where I want to add a new column with a default value *and* a not null constraint like below:

```
add_column :blog, :published, :boolean, default: false, null: false
```

Ankane's Strong Migration [gem](https://github.com/ankane/strong_migrations#adding-a-column-with-a-default-value) says; adding a new column with a default value is safe and does not require a table rewrite.

Is *still safe* when **combined** with a null constraint? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if there are no existing data the null constraint is safe but if you want to add a column and populate it with existing data, and the existing data could be null your data migration will fail.

Comment: Thanks! Just ran the migration on a table with 1.5M rows without any issues.

Comment: For more technical explanation: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/312041/73037

Comment: I did 3 migrations on 3 different tables. 2 of them worked like a charm, but for some reason it did end up locking the whole DB for 121 seconds on the third migration.  Just be careful and split if you can.